# Belt too long, tie with two knots?

Tags: tae-kwon-do, belt

I use the classic one knot belt tie, but the tied belt is quite long (almost touches the knees), and I’m wondering if I could use two knots.

I tried doing it, but the result was too “bulky” and I gave up on it.

Searching the web I only find references to the classic single knot.

Is this something that I can use? If so, how could the double knot be done?

It was earned in a belt test, so I prefer to not replace it with a bought one. In case it may be relevant, this is a Taekwondo belt.

Comment: Which style is this for? Tae Kwan Do? Karate? Kung Fu? Capoeira? And what organization or style?

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but belts do come in different length, and cost around $10 (unless it's an embroidered brown/black belt, obviously). Any reason why switching to a shorter belt isn't possible/desirable?

Comment: Didn’t think it mattered: it’s Taekwondo.

Comment: I reworded the title, so that it really addresses the underlying problem - a long belt - and makes it open to more answers.

Comment: @DanielReis: I asked because different styles have different traditions on how to tie the belt, which might constrain the possible suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that just requesting another belt at your school (they often have a closet full of them) isn't viable, and you don't want to buy another one, the other two options I've seen is to loop it a third time (the traditional method for TKD belts wrapping twice) or tying the second knot as per [these instructions](https://www.reddit.com/r/martialarts/comments/1bsg26/any_good_methods_to_shorten_a_belt/c99mgvz?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x):

> I tinkered around with this for a few minutes and this is what I came up with. Just when you are about to pull the ends of your belt to tighten it, take the end on your right (if you're looking down at your belt) and bring it back up and [through the loop at the top](https://i.imgur.com/16bLBD5). Then take the other end and put it through the [loop you just created](https://i.imgur.com/gi2cWtO). This creates a bigger knot, and just might be a pain in the ass to workout with, but it will reduce the length of the ends by about 4 inches.

Comment: I wonder if you are referring to a double overhand knot.  Most belts are tied with a sort of square knot, with the first overhand enclosing the belt wraps only once; a double overhand would do the same but with two wraps.  Kind of like what is here:  https://www.indoorclimbing.com/Overhand_Knot.html.  If so, you're right, this would work and may not look funky, especially if the 2nd overhand didn't also need to be a double overhand.

Answer (score 4):

It is common to see very long belts in Taekwondo, not sure why.  However, double knot is probably not what you want; rather, try an extra wrap around the waist.  I haven't seen the double knot, but I doubt it would be enough to deal with belt at the knees.

Failing that, you'll need to ask for, or buy, another belt.